# In an elf file, how to find which compile unit the variable is defined?

Tags: elf, dwarf

I'm writing a tool to add variables to a2l file, the input is elf file.
For searching which compile unit (CU) has the variable, I have to search through all CUs (till meet the variable).
Because the SW is very big, it takes time to find a variable.
I would like to know if there's any faster way to know which CU the variable is defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DWARF standard includes an **optional** section, `.debug_pubnames`, that provides name-to-offset translation for **global** objects and functions.

Another approach is to use the symbol table.  If it has an entry for the variable then you can use its address with the **optional** `.debug_aranges` section or, failing that, read every `DW_TAG_compile_unit` looking for the one with the enclosing address range.